# Error creating an archive node via `tezos-node reconstruct`

Tags: archive-node

I'm attempting to convert a "full" Tezos node into an "archive" using the command `tezos-node reconstruct`. It ran for about 10 days (!) and finally crashed () with the following error:

```
Sep 29 22:12:42.872 - node.reconstruction: resuming reconstruction from block
Sep 29 22:12:42.872 - node.reconstruction:   BMeHwhB7EgXXxrR9N8enrVeyKCL2wMYXFcoToJZNc57Us4bRUPF (level: 1341460) toward
Sep 29 22:12:42.872 - node.reconstruction:   block BM14mbCPfA5txPwJ5NKHGsqxXVzCRAYQJNXLFtT5AmAbDHqEKj4 (level: 1628180)
Sep 29 22:12:42.872 - node.reconstruction: enumerating all blocks to reconstruct
Reconstructing cemented blocks: 328/403 cycles rebuilt Done
tezos-node: Error:
              The data contained in the storage is not valid. The reconstruction procedure failed: resulting context hash for block BKpJVfDq5BkSPQpJFiJumZxnWs7GM9zZJjRkScaoqWLSCUDYMdJ (level 1343489) does not match. Context hash expected CoWDvvmu2ttnciFNMhXrky6xCBWnShRVm4v9CNjvWshJFWMLBeqG, got CoUkGUAiSRpvXNTvRmomMxrnFKAreGZSrVf7H4dGkVotrtJGL1Zs.
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? I was using the node as a "full" node before and it worked fine.

Here's the `tezos-node` version string: `5bfd311b (2021-09-01 19:44:02 +0200) (10.2)`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is a know issue which seems to occur in a non deterministic way and there is currently no fix.
There are already several issues referencing this problem. Feel free to follow them to get information regarding an upcoming fix.

https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/issues/1679 and https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/issues/1729

Comment: Thanks. Any suggestions on how to proceed? Do I just start again? And is there any way to avoid the 10+ days it takes to run the upgrade from "full" to "archive"?

Comment: If you really need an archive node, the only alternative is to bootstrap from scratch. But it is a bit longer

Comment: That's what I'm doing now, and it actually looks like it'll be faster - at the current rate I think it should be done in less than a week.